# How to add events to TForm's descendant?

Tags: delphi-7

I'm using Delphi 7

I would like to have a new event for a TForm's descendant let's say OnApprove (which will be execute on a toolbar clicking), and I would like this new event to appear on the object inspector.

Please suggest me what to do?

Thanks.

Comment: Here is a wayback cache of the mentioned article: [link](http://web.archive.org/web/20101127061542/http://mustangpeak.net/ota_publishedprop_forms.htm)